# how can a call a function when text value of my textbox changes using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 input fields which have values prepopulated and a constant value of total hours 200. I am calculating the avghours as totalhours/datediff of date1 and date2.

My Question is if i change the value of date2 then i want the avghours value to change accordingly. I am not sure which event should be used to fire the method which does the calculation

```
<input type="text" id ="avghours"/>
<input type="text" id ="date1"/>
<input type="text" id ="date2"/>
```

Javascript code

```
 function getavg()
 {

 $('#avghours').val()=totalhours/datediff($('#date2').val(),$('#date1').val(),'day');//datediff is userdefined function to get the datedifference


 }
```

change will fire only if the focus is lost so that might not be possible is there anyother event that i can use.

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$('#avghours').val()=totalhours/datediff($('#date2').val(),
                                             $('#date1').val(),'day');
```

to

```
 $("#date2").bind("keyup blur change mouseup",function () {
     var d = parseInt(datediff($('#date2').val());
     var v = (totalhours/d) + ' ' + $('#date1').val() + ' day'; <-- mergestrings
     $('#avghours').val(v);
 });
```

assign via the function instead of the right hand.

Comment: i couldnt understand why the mergestring? datediff was a userdefined function to calulate the date difference. Or am i missing something very obvious?

Comment: no, I understand your correct code, however, I prefer to keep it a bit readable ;)

Comment: oh ok... i got it now... but would keyup work if keyboard is not used. i mean like its pasted using mouse

Comment: edited that a bit, added a bunch of events you can select according your requirements.

Comment: oh tats cool.. didnt know you could add bunch of events like this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update it immediately when the user types you could use the keyup event.

Comment: what happens if the user doesnot use the keyboard he pastes the date from another field using mouse would this event fire?

Answer (score 0):

you could try keypress so...

```
$('#date2').keypress(function() {
//do calculating average logic here
});
```

then this would pick up when the value of the textbox has been changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`.change()`** event for this.

```
$("#date2").change(function(){

});
```

Comment: change event fires only if the focus is lost

Answer (score 0):

```
    [![<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>

function multy(val)
{
alert(val.value+"--"+val.id);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="txtdemo" type="text" onchange="multy(this);"></br>
<input id="txtdemo" type="text" onchange="multy(this);">
</input>
</body>
</html>][1]][1]
```